# Sort dictionary as per length of values

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

```
d={
    1:[1,2,3,4],
    2:[5,4],
    3:[5,6,7]
}
```

Given a dictionary, we need to sort the dictionary as per the length of values (in this case, as per length of lists)

Output should be as below:

```
{1:[1,2,3,4],3:[5,6,7],2:[5,4]}
```

Please help me with the code

Comment: `d = {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: -len(t[1]))}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Hi Samwise,
Is it possible to sort the list values also at the same time?

Comment: Harshita: Sure it is, but that's not the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way if you are sure that your keys will be integers:**

```
d = {key: value for key, value in sorted(d.items())}
```